# How to load a NIB inside of a view in another NIB?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I have two NIB's

```
ParentViewController.xib
ChildViewController.xib
```

ParentViewController.xib contains a UIView and a UIViewController.
ChildViewController.xib contains a UIButton

**I want ChildViewController.xib to load in the ParentViewController.xib's UIView**

I have done the following:

1. Created @property for UIView in ParentViewController
2. Connected File's Owner to UIView in ParentViewController
3. Set UIViewController in ParentViewController's NIB Name property to ChildViewController in Interface Builder
4. Set ChildViewController view property to UIView in ParentViewController

I was hoping this would load ChildViewController into my UIView in ParentViewController but no luck.

I did get the following warning, which could be the culprit:

```
'View Controller (Child View)' has both its 'NIB Name' property set and its 'view' outlet connected. This configuration is not supported.
```

I also have added additional code in ParentViewController's viewDidLoad():

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ChildViewController *childViewController = [[ChildViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ChildViewController" bundle:nil]; 
    childViewController.view = self.myView; 
}
```

Any thoughts on why ChildViewController does not load in the UIView of ParentViewController?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
[self.myview addSubview: childViewController.view];
```

instead of

```
childViewController.view = self.myView;
```

Comment: Is is possible to do it using Interface Builder ?

Answer (score 5):

The alternative is to build the "embedded" view (!) in a Nib, say `ChildView.xib`, then instantiate it in the `ParentViewController.xib` (change the class in the Identity inspector). There is no need to programmatically `[self.view addSubview:embeddedView]` in the parent view controller's `-viewDidLoad` method.

I wrote up how we [embed custom-view Nibs inside other Nibs](http://blog.compeople.eu/apps/?p=142) in a longish blog post. The crux is overriding `-awakeAfterUsingCoder:` in the `ChildView` class, replacing the object loaded from the "parent" Nib with the one loaded from the "child" Nib.

Note that our custom controls subclass `UIView`, not `UIViewController` (see [Apple's docs on Custom view controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH112-SW12): "You should not use multiple custom view controllers to manage different portions of the same view hierarchy.")

Comment: Well did you check the 'Container View Controllers Arrange Content of Other View Controllers' part from the link you provided... as of iOS5 you have the option of UIViewController containment.

Comment: Link to your blogpost is dead btw.

Comment: @ruslan: Works for me… Anyway, here is an update:  http://blog.yangmeyer.de/blog/2012/07/09/an-update-on-nested-nib-loading

Comment: Blog page broken